# How to get '^?'-style type annotations in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, typescript-playground

In TS Playground, they have this feature `// ^?`, which shows the entire type signature for the symbol above it.
[image]

How do I get the same effect in VSCode or Neovim?

Comment: It's not google friendly with the actual symbols, but you can search for extensions by its full name "typescript twoslash" - https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/twoslash/ , https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript/twoslash

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature/plugin called *"two slash"* (thanks to [kikon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16466946/kikon) for letting me know about it).

In VSCode you can download the plugin [`vscode-twoslash-queries` by Orta](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries).

In Neovim there's a plugin called [`twoslash-queries` by marilari88](https://github.com/marilari88/twoslash-queries.nvim).